# Php ajax just want to display error message only form submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

After send my form data to php file its return if any error found. But its also return success before ajax redirect page. I want display error message only and if success, redirect another page.

ajax:

```
$("#msform").submit(function(){
     $.ajax({
           type:"post",
           url:"pagesubmit.php",
           data:  $("#msform").serialize(),
           dataType : 'json',
           success: function(data){
           if ( ! data.success) {
                $(".help-block").fadeIn().html(data.error);
           } else {
                $(".help-block").fadeOut();
                $("#msform")[0].reset();
                window.location = 'http://dbsvawdez.com/' + data.success;
           }
           }
     });
});
```

php:

```
include_once ("db.php");
global $dbh;

function check($name){
  if(!$name || strlen($name = trim($name)) == 0){
     $error ="* Username not entered";
  }
  else{
     $name = stripslashes($name);
     if(strlen($name) < 5){
        $error ="* Name below 5 characters";
     }
     else if(!preg_match("/^([0-9a-z])+$/i", $name)){
        $error ="* Name not alphanumeric";
     }
     else {
        return 1;  
     }
  } 
}

  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh, $_POST['name']);

  $thisname = strtolower($name);

  $retval = check($thisname);

  if($retval ==1){ // if no error found
   $success ='upage/userpage?user='.$_SESSION['username'].'';                           
  }


$data = array();
$data['error'] = $error;
$data['success'] = $success;
if (!empty($data)) {
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem, in this way:

Ajax:

```
$("#msform").submit(function(){
// collect input name
ver name = var catag=$('#name').val();
   $.ajax({
       type:"post",
       url:"pagesubmit.php",
       data:  $("#msform").serialize(),
       success: function(data){
       if ( data != 'success') {
            $(".help-block").fadeIn().html(data);
       } else {
            $(".help-block").fadeOut();
            $("#msform")[0].reset();
            window.location = 'http://dbsvawdez.com/' + name;
       }
       }
   });
});
```

php:

```
function check($name){
    if(!$name || strlen($name = trim($name)) == 0){
    echo "* Username not entered";
    }
    else{
        $name = stripslashes($name);
        if(strlen($name) < 5){
        echo "* Name below 5 characters";
        }
        else if(!preg_match("/^([0-9a-z])+$/i", $name)){
        echo "* Name not alphanumeric";
        }
        else {
        return 1;  
        }
    } 
}

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh, $_POST['name']);
$thisname = strtolower($name);
$retval = check($thisname);
if($retval ==1){ // if no error found
   echo 'success';                         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Set your variables `$success` and `$error`

```
$success = "";
$error= "";
```

If you doesn't init them, you cannot use them and the `.=`operator is for concatenation not for set.

Then you should encode the response in php in JSON.

Something like

```
$response = json_encode(
    array(  
        'success'=> true,  
        'route' => "mypage/info?user=$_SESSION['username']"
    )
);
```

And return this, then access your response like you already do :

```
var success = response.success;
```

**UPDATE**

change this code to add an `else` statement :

```
if($retval ==1){ // if no error found
    $success ='upage/userpage?user='.$_SESSION['username'].'';                           
}else{
    $success = 'error';
}
```

and this line :

```
else {
    return 1;  
}
```

to :

```
else {
   $error = 'none';
}
```

and in your javascript :

```
$("#msform").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type     :"post",
        url      :"pagesubmit.php",
        data     :  $("#msform").serialize(),
        dataType : 'json',
        success  : function(data){
            if(data.success == 'error') {
                $(".help-block").fadeIn().html(data.error);
            }else{
                $(".help-block").fadeOut();
                $("#msform")[0].reset();
                window.location = 'http://dbsvawdez.com/' + data.success;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please see my update, In case of error, php console display `{"error":null,"success":null}`  no error display also.

Comment: Why use "JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES" ?
You dont init your variables `$error` and `$success`
Look my edit

Comment: Updated; can you give me more detail please. Here success redirect well but error not show and console display `{"error":null,"success":null}`. Its may be my short of knowledge. Thank u.

Comment: Try to set your `$error` and `$success` variable after `global $dbh;` like this `$error='test'; $success='test';`

Comment: Not working; Its cannot get any value inside from php function like `$error ="* Name below 5 characters";` If I set it at outside of function, Its work. How to solved it.

Comment: Have you tested my solution in last update and replace all the lines ?

Comment: yaa. commented after test. Thank u.